# IPM IGBT Module pins

Tags: diodes, igbt, module

This is a internal circuit of [PSS30S71F6](https://octopart.com/datasheet/pss30s71f6-powerex-34828850)and datasheet is attached.
I would like to ask you what are Vufs (1) and Vufb (3) pins for?
This pins are keep burning for a reason but i haven't figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

Vufs (1) and Vufb (3) pins are used for "bootstrapping" circuits (diode +Capacitors).

See figure 6 of datasheet + remark (7).

[image]

Comment: What kind of things might cause Vufs and Vufb pins explosion? It's happen one in every 20-30 circuits

Comment: Don't know. Are PSS3071F6 anymore usable?